# Class model in payment system

Tags: php, oop, object, data-modeling

I need help about the structure about a payment system. Here is how it works: Manager give to Seller an item. This item can be sold at any price and the Manager will receive a percentage. When Seller sells that item to Customer I need to save two payments. Customer->Seller and Seller->Manager. So I have created three classes:

**Payment**

```
class Payment{

private $id;

private $item;

private $date;

private $status;

private $amount;
}
```

**Payment_Customer**

```
class Payment_Customer extends Payment{

private $frequency;

private $rating;

private $amount_paid;

}
```

**Payment_Seller**

```
class Payment_Seller extends Payment{

private $percentage;

private $amount_due;

private $max_date;

}
```

But now I have a problem because I need an object 'entire payment' that contains both payment types so I added an object Payment_Customer and Payment_Seller into Payment class that now looks like this:

```
class Payment{

private $id;

private $date;

private $status;

private $amount;

private $payment_customer;

private $payment_seller;
}
```

That's wrong! What could be a good solution for this? Create a new class **Entire_Payment** which contains both payment types? Or change classes model? Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is object of `Payment` class should always operate both `Payment_Customer` and `Payment_Seller` objects ?

Comment: no, just after saving them